# Natural cubic spline using patsy cr

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, spline, smoothing

I am trying to make natural cubic spline using `patsy` library.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from patsy import cr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = df.age #some data
y = df.wage

x_basis = cr(x, df=15)
model = LinearRegression().fit(x_basis, y)
y_hat = model.predict(x_basis)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y_hat, 'r')
plt.show()
```

The output is the following:
[image]

I believe that there should be one line. How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a plotting issue. The [plt.plot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) function draws by default a *line plot* without markers. Since your data is not sorted by `x` variable, the line jumps back and forth making the result look messy. I generated sample data and plotted with `plt.plot` defaults and then by hiding the line, and adding markers. The results are

#### With default `plt.plot` arguments

*Rest of the code below (not repeated for convenience)*

```py
spline_basis = patsy.cr(x, df=3)
model = LinearRegression().fit(spline_basis, y)
y_spline = model.predict(spline_basis)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y_spline, color="red")
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### With `plt.plot` when `marker='.'` and `ls=''`

*Rest of the code below (not repeated for convenience)*

```py
spline_basis = patsy.cr(x, df=3)
model = LinearRegression().fit(spline_basis, y)
y_spline = model.predict(spline_basis)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y_spline, ls="", marker=".", color="red") # Only this changed
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### By reordering data

*Rest of the code below (not repeated for convenience)*
If you want to draw a *line plot*, you could just reorder the data for fitting, like this:

```
spline_basis = patsy.cr(x, df=3)
model = LinearRegression().fit(spline_basis, y)
y_spline = model.predict(spline_basis)
plt.scatter(x, y)
xsorted, ysorted = zip(*[(X, Y) for (X, Y) in sorted(zip(x, y_spline))]) # simple reordering
plt.plot(xsorted, ysorted, color="red")
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### By using new data for prediction

Usually, models are created **for prediction**. The idea is to create model with *training data* and then use the model with some **new data**. This new data can be anything. If it is sorted, it can be plotted as lineplot. In this case, you can create new x-values, for example

```
new_x = np.linspace(10, 100, 100)
```

and calculate the predicted y-values for them. For this, you need to know (and save) only few values. Actually, just `df`, `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` and the 4 floats from `model._coef`.

```py
# Fit model
spline_basis = patsy.cr(x, df=3, lower_bound=x.min(), upper_bound=x.max())
model = LinearRegression().fit(spline_basis, y)
y_train = model.predict(spline_basis)

# Use model
new_x = np.linspace(10, 100, 100)  # 100 points
spline_basis_new = patsy.cr(new_x, df=3, lower_bound=x.min(), upper_bound=x.max())
new_y = model.predict(spline_basis_new)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y_train, color="red", ls="", marker=".")
plt.plot(new_x, new_y, color="green")
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Rest of the code

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import patsy
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


def dummy_data():
    np.random.seed(1)

    x = np.random.choice(np.arange(18, 81), size=4000)

    def model(x):
        a = 83 / 107520
        b = -895 / 5376
        c = 17747 / 1680
        d = -622 / 7
        return a * x ** 3 + b * x ** 2 + c * x + d

    def noisemodel(x):
        an = -0.0591836734693878
        bn = 5.25510204081633
        cn = -31.6326530612245
        return an * x ** 2 + bn * x + cn

    y = model(x)
    ynoise = np.array([np.random.randn() * noisemodel(_) for _ in x])

    return x, y + ynoise


x, y = dummy_data()
```

Comment: Regarding the new data points part, if I have only one x in production for example, how should I apply cr and then use the saved model?

Comment: You would need to save the `df`, `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` (three numbers) which you used with the training data to create new spline basis with [patsy.cr](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API-reference.html#patsy.cr). Saving the regression model created with sklearn [possible with pickle](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html). Although, if you have just a linear model, all you need to do is to save the `model._coef` and after that predictions are just matrix multiplication.

Comment: Many thanks @np8! But here are we still assuming x has multiple values so that we can indeed apply it like cr(x_new, df=10, constraints="center", lower_bound=x.min(), upper_bound=x.max())? Suppose my x_new is 150 and I'd like to get corresponding smoothed values [which has 1 x 10 dimension] so that I could use this in my linear regression. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not on computer right now but would it work if you just created an np.array with just one value? If not, I guess it would be best to create a new question. I am not sure what kind of prerequisites the patsy.cr has for its inputs.

Comment: you can find my question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66107014/how-to-use-the-smoothed-line-with-patsy-cr-in-production. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Bruh, sort your values before passing to a patsy function.

*DSBA Piazza Teacher Assistant Team*